# How does one remove a certificate authority's certificate from a system?

Tags: certificates

The `ca-certificates` package was just updated, and it caused the following changes on my Xubuntu 13.10 system:

```
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....
Adding debian:CA_Disig_Root_R1.pem
Adding debian:CA_Disig_Root_R2.pem
Adding debian:China_Internet_Network_Information_Center_EV_Certificates_Root.pem
Adding debian:D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_2009.pem
Adding debian:D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_EV_2009.pem
Adding debian:PSCProcert.pem
Adding debian:StartCom_Certification_Authority_2.pem
Adding debian:Swisscom_Root_CA_2.pem
Adding debian:Swisscom_Root_EV_CA_2.pem
Adding debian:TURKTRUST_Certificate_Services_Provider_Root_2007.pem
Adding debian:Verisign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_2.pem
Removing debian:cacert.org_class3.pem
Removing debian:cacert.org_root.pem
Removing debian:Equifax_Secure_eBusiness_CA_2.pem
Removing debian:TC_TrustCenter_Universal_CA_III.pem
```

I've decided I don't trust some of these CAs, and I would like to remove their certificates. How do I do that?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

That should give you a list where you can deselect CAs.

The list of CAs is stored in the file `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`. If you edit this file manually you need to run

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

to update the actual certificates in `/etc/ssl/certs/` (if you use `dpkg-reconfigure` that is done automatically).

See `/usr/share/doc/ca-certificates/README.Debian` for more information.

Comment: This worked flawlessly and was far easier than I expected it would be. The Debian contributors deserve a lot of credit for making it so painless. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: ensure you don't have a package manager open.

Comment: I downloaded a certificate, when I double click on it, gcr-viewer opens and allows me to import it using root password. But after the import, the file /etc/ca-certificates.conf does not contain it, any idea? here the question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/749073/how-to-uninstall-a-certificate-imported-thru-gcr-viewer