# Where are these certificates coming from?

Tags: aptitude, ssl, openssl, etc, certificates

On an Ubuntu 12.04 server I have a bunch of certificates listed in my /etc/ssl directory...where could these have come from? I don't remember adding them myself, do they get generated when aptitude updates its repos or is it from something else?

Comment: so, from the duplicate link `dpkg -S  /etc/ssl/some_cert`

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html

Answer (score 1):

The certificates are from the package [ca-certificates](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ca-certificates). The files in `/etc/ssl/certs` are actually symlinks managed by [update-ca-certificates](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html).

See [How does one remove a certificate authority's certificate from a system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440580/how-does-one-remove-a-certificate-authoritys-certificate-from-a-system/) if you want to remove some of them.