# Proper way to Remove Certificate from trust list

Tags: apt, ssl

I have to add to a trust list my self signed certificate ,but now I need to remove it

I am looking for the proper way to do so, without braking the system

This is the way I added:

I copied the certificate at this location:

```
/usr/local/share/ca-certificates
```

the I run the command:

```
update-ca-certificates
```

Now I need to remove it, because I need to create a wild card certificate and again add it to a trust list

I can see the certificate in:

```
/etc/ssl/certs
```

and I've been thinking to just remove it from both locations and run again

```
update-ca-certificates
```

but I am not sure, if this will work

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one remove a certificate authority's certificate from a system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440580/how-does-one-remove-a-certificate-authoritys-certificate-from-a-system)

Comment: Sorry no. Seems my new certificate is not on this list, because is self signed or I haven't configured properly

Answer (score -1):

I manually edited the file `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

But I'm not confident this is the correct approach, however removing the file `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` did not remove the cert from `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`